# Andengine Portrait Screen Coordinate

Tags: android, andengine

can any body say what is the (X,Y) coordinates of screen when portrait screen is choosen?
For example:

> Left-Down  = 0,0 Left-Up    = 800,0 Right-Down = 480,0 Right-Up   =
>   800,480

is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I thhink it's like that for AndEngine AnchorCenter Branch:

Left-Bottom 0, 0

Left-Top **0, 800**

Right-Bottom 480, 0

Right-Top **480, 800**

And for the older branch 0, 0 is left-top and and left-bottom is 0, 800